# VBA Call each sub from a procedure.VBA Re-enter a For Next Loop to continue with the next iteration

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write a program which will find all the values of x and y which will satisfy the condition of x + 2*y equalling say 5. I've given this simple example for the sake of clarity.

Note: I've used nested calls successfully  but the program to me looks messy and ill-structured.

In an effort to clean up the structure of my coding I've tried to code the following without much success. Is there any way the following can be done in VBA and how is it done? I have my back against the wall and am hoping that you can help, please.

Please note that the following is not meant to be code but a way of explaining my query. So here is what I envisage  to clean up the structure (Simplified for clarity):

```
Sub sbCaller()
    Call sbForLoop()
    Call sbMakeEquation()
    Call sbTestEquation()
    Call sbTabulate()
End Sub
```

from sbCaller() execute Call sbForLoop()

```
'simplified for the sake of clarity:-
    For x = 1 To 4

        For y = 1 To 4

           'Go back to Sub sbCaller() to execute sbMakeEquation()
        Result = x + 2*y

    'back in sbTestEquation()
        If Result = 5 Then go back to Sub sbCaller() to execute sbTabulate()

if Result<> 5 Then go back to Sub sbForLoop to resume execution at 
    'point HERE to execute the next iteration.
```

Comment: Are there more constraints? This could run for a very long time especially if negative numbers are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the approach you propose is too complicated. Especially if you intend to stick with "Sub" instead of "Function".

The following separates the steps, which is what I understand you to want, without needing to jump back-and-forth within the same procedure.

```
Sub sbCaller()
    sbForLoop
End Sub

Sub sbForLoop()
    Dim result As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

    For x = 1 To 4
        For y = 1 To 4
            result = x + 2 * y
            sbTestEquation result, x, y
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub

Function sbTestEquation(result As Long, x As Long, y As Long) As Boolean
    Dim bOK As Boolean

    If result = 5 Then
        sbTabulate result, x, y
        bOK = True
    Else
        bOK = False
    End If
    sbTestEquation = bOK
End Function

Sub sbTabulate(result As Long, x As Long, y As Long)
    Debug.Print result, x, y
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Cindy Meister. It’s the guidance I needed as I’m a self taught VBA enthusiast!! I thought I was doing the correct thing by putting all my calls to the appropriate procedures in sbCaller. It certainly became too complicated as I couldn’t figure out how to return to the appropriate procedure calls in sbCaller. Can it be done using functions?

Comment: Functions don't make the construction any easier - you can just pass back information more easily. But in order to "go backwards" in the code you'd need to use what's known as "label" with `GoTo` instructions. This is something we used to do in the old mainframe days, before programming languages became more sophisticated. Now it's definitely *not* the accepted approach. Breaking things down into procedures where each procedure is responsible for one task is currently the way things "are done".

Comment: Hi again Cindy Meister. Yes I’ve been warned off using GoTo instructions for exactly the same reasons you quote. I will certainly implement the code you kindly provided by incorporating it into my final coding and will update you in due course. Once again, Many thanks.

Comment: Attn Cindy Meister: Your code is a springboard to using the power of functions and has opened up new possibilities. Thanks for getting me over the hump!!